# How to change the label of a MenuItem in a PyGTK application?

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, pygtk, indicator

I'm writing a small Application Indicator for Ubuntu in Python. I need to change the text of an insensitive (disabled) gtk.MenuItem. I know a living example for this function, the topmost item in the built-in Bluetooth Indicator.

Answer (score 7):

The `gtk.MenuItem` is a container that usually has the actual label as its child widget, unless there is something more complicated like an image involved; if the child is just a simple label, you should be able to do

```
menuitem.get_child().set_text('New text')
```

Comment: +1; I was skeptical, but I tested this and it worked. Good call.

Comment: Hum, this did not work for me however `get_child().set_label()` did as there is no such `set_title()` method in my [version of pygtk](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkmenuitem.html).

Comment: It's this [`set_text()`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtklabel.html#method-gtklabel--set-text) method. `set_label()` should work as well, although it's not quite the same.